# Opengl: where do I find freeglut.dll in freeglut (extracted .tar file)?

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2017, freeglut

I am trying to install OpenGL in the Microsoft visual studio(professional of community version). I have downloaded glew and freeglut(.tar file). In installation steps, I learn that freeglut.dll and glew32.dll files need to be copied into certain location in visual studio. But not able to find the freeglut.dll anywhere in the extracted freeglut (.tar) file. How do I need to proceed? How to finally get OpenGL installed?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the tar file, you need the zip file.

You can get it here: http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/

Direct download link: http://files.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/development/GLUT/freeglut-MSVC.zip